# connecting to databases using spring and hibernate - primary and secondary databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi this is what I am looking to do -

I have three databases - each exactly the same - one is primary and two and three are back ups.

I am using hibernate and spring to connect to the data base.I have spring application context file configured with 3 session factories, and 3 corresponding data sources.

I was wondering if there is a way using spring where if the application is not able to connect to the database 1  (an exception is thrown) it will connect to database 2 - and in turn is database 3 is down it will connect to 3 and proceed.

What would be the best way to implement this? I have read about AbstractRoutingDataSource ..but not sure how to make use of that in this case..also if there are other ideas.. Would appreciate some directions. Thanks!

this is my config in application context xml -

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="$g{jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$g{url1}" />
        <property name="user" value="$l{uid1}" />
        <property name="password" value="$l{pwd1}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="$g{jdbc.preferredTestQuery}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="$g{jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckout}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">$g{jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">$g{jdbc.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="$g{jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$g{url2}" />
        <property name="user" value="$l{uid2}" />
        <property name="password" value="$l{pwd2}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="$g{jdbc.preferredTestQuery}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="$g{jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckout}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">$g{jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">$g{jdbc.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource3" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="$g{jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="$g{url3}" />
        <property name="user" value="$l{uid3}" />
        <property name="password" value="$l{pwd3}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="$g{jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="$g{jdbc.preferredTestQuery}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="$g{jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckout}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory3"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource3" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">$g{jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">$g{jdbc.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager3"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory3" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: I don't know of a Spring way to do that. What I think is more typical is to have one DataSource configured and use DNS to direct connections to the desired (currently up-and-running) database. Then, your application's connection pool just keeps retrying when it fails to connect and once the DNS TTL has expired it will be directed to the new server and a connection will be established. We usually use a DNS TTL of 60 seconds or less in this type of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this by using Spring Abstract Data Source Routing mechanism -

https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/